# Malfunction SOQL Query

Tags: soql, knowledge, data-category

I have the below Data Categories

```
Group1
     Category1
     Category2
Group2
```

Now the query which I am trying to execute is below to get all the articles in published state and linked with Group 2, but the query is giving the malfunction error in workbench. Any help

```
SELECT Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' WITH DATA CATEGORY Group2__c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The syntax of the data category selection in a [WITH DATA CATEGORY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory_catselection.htm#only_filteringSelector)
>   clause in a SOQL query includes a category group name to use as a
>   filter, the filter selector, and the **name of the category** to use for
>   filtering.

If you want to select all the article in a group use the ABOVE_OR_BELOW  filter selector like this: `SELECT Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' WITH DATA CATEGORY Group1__c ABOVE_OR_BELOW Category1__c`

See [Filtering Selectors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory_filterselectors.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory_filterselectors) for a list of valid selectors.

In your case, I believe there is no category under group2, so your query should look like this: `SELECT Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' WITH DATA CATEGORY Group2__c AT All__c`